# Div Alignment FireFox, IE7, IE6

Tags: css, html, css-float

I am having problems aligning a couple divs in IE6, IE7, IE8 and Firfox 3. They all don't render correct what IE8 and Firefox like the rest don't.

Is it possible to do this via floats and clears.. they dont need to have any spacing between them, I just drew it this way.... Also, the div's should be fixed widths.

[alt text http://cowfarm.net/divAlign.png](http://cowfarm.net/divAlign.png)

Comment: Some code would help to see what could be the problem exactly.

Comment: This would be easy to do, what order do you want the divs to appear in the HTML source? can you number them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get equal heights for the 2 left DIVs combined and the right DIV. Unless ofcourse you specify those, or if the contents produce the same heights... But this shouldn't be a problem i think?

**Update**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container {float:right;position:relative;}
    #left    {float:left;}
    #left_1  {float:left;}
    #left_2  {clear:left;float:left;}
    #right   {float:right;}
    #bottom  {float:left;clear:both;}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="left_1">left 1</div>
        <div id="left_2">left 2</div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">right</div>

    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: with fixed widths in firefox it is causing #right to position under left2 and in ie this is causing #right to to float all the way to the right of the page...

Comment: could it be with fixed widths that the container is too small to fit both left and right DIVs next to each other?

Comment: There is no need to float #right, you can just give it a left margin bigger than or equal to the width of the left divs

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it should even work without the container div, although like I said, I would give the right div a left margin and not float it.

Comment: yeah so thats the problem :), without the container div right is floating all the way to the right side of the page, could this be fixed? by adding another div that is as long as left1, left2, and bottom?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this is possible:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan='2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm only kidding, of course.

Comment: +1 Because that actually works; and it works EVERYWHERE.  You guys with the "tablephobia" need to get over it.